# SQL Server 2008 DATE type showes me DATE & TIME in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and my fields have `DATE` type but in Visual Studio in my program when I read may data it shows me `DATE & TIME` what should I do? I try to cast my fields in `SELECT` query of my program but it gives me some error,how can I solve this problem?

This is my behind code:

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection(Class1.CnnStr);
                SqlDataReader reader;


                cmd.CommandText = "select ContractStartDate,MandateValidDate from table where BrokerName=@BrokerName";
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BrokerName", BrokerName_txt.Text);
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.Read())
                {


                    ContractStartDate_txt.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["ContractStartDate"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    MandateValidDate_txt.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["MandateValidDate"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");               
                    reader.Close();
                }
                cmd.Connection.Close();

            }
```

and because I want to save data after read them it gives me error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Coz what you have is `DateTime`, you can choose only to use the '.Date` property or `ToString("dd/MM/YYYY")` on the datetime instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use [Convert.ToDateTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t.aspx) to convert the strings returned from the database first, later by using [DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm) you can get only Date value from the Date & Time.

```
ContractStartDate_txt.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["ContractStartDate"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
MandateValidDate_txt.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["MandateValidDate"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: adding to your answer, you can also do Convert.ToDateTime(reader["ContractStartDate"]).ToShortDateString();

Comment: @mehul9595 my colleague used that approach in some code, which caused a bunch of tests to break when we ran them on a machine with different CurrentCulture settings.  It's not a good idea.

Comment: @phoog: using DateTime.Parse() method would be a good solution in that case. eg: DateTime.Parse(reader["ContractStartDate"], CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture).ToShortDateString();

Comment: @KatyJ, can you repost the code which you modified in your question now?

Answer (score 0):

You have a casting issue and need to convert to the correct collation for the DB

i.e db may want `01/23/2011` US format and you have `23/01/2011` as UK/Aus format

you can either fix at Code or at db up to you ..

a`string.format("dd/mmm/yyyy");` as the parameter

```
CONVERT(CHAR, @adate,103)
```

We always pass 26Feb2011 string to DB that way we bypass collation issues

Answer (score 0):

Date types typically map to the DateTime type (with a time component representing midnight).  Use the overload of ToString that accepts a format argument (for example, someDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Using the ISO year-first format avoids the day-month-year vs. month-day-year ambiguity, without relying on using words for the month names.

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to do formatting on the datetime and one of the simple way is fetch the data from the required table in the desired format.
Like here you need to display the date and if you your format is dd/MM/yyyy then try this

```
select Convert(varchar(10),ContractStartDate,103) as ContractStartDateformat,,MandateValidDate from table where BrokerName=@BrokerName
```

[Cast and Convert, Check this out just in case if you need different date format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)